# mobx reaction unstable, cyclic function

Tags: reactive-programming, mobx

I'm trying to use MobX to create an Otello game. So I have reaction to look for tile changes and then update other tiles accordingly.

So in the code below, I ran `bumpRandom()` to change another tile to see the effect. But then this goes into cyclic function cause `reaction` is alway ran. How do I get it to stop observing in a `reaction`?

```
class OtelloBoard {
  @observable cells = [];

  constructor() {
    for (i = 0; i< SIZE*SIZE; i++) {
      this.cells.push(new Cell())
    }
    reaction(
      () => this.cells.map( cell => cell.status ),
      status => {
        this.bumpRandom()
        console.log('Status has changed' + status)
      }
    )
  }

  @action bumpRandom() {
    this.cells[45].bump()
  }
}
```

I tried `untracked(() => this.bumpRandom())` but that doesn't work either.

Comment: So right now that is going to run every time a cell changes. Since it also changes a cell it's going to keep calling itself endlessly. You need to add some logic in your reaction to ensure it only calls bumpRandom when the initiating cell changes and not the resulting changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking in [this MobX issue](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/528), I found a solution by not using reaction. I'm using `@action` instead, and have it run `onClick()`

```
class OtelloBoard {
  @observable cells = [];

  constructor() {
   for (i = 0; i< SIZE*SIZE; i++) {
  this.cells.push(new Cell())
}
}

 @action bumpRandom() {
  this.cells[45].bump()
 } 
}
```